# ajax-chosen doesnt work well with selection and styling

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have used Chosen plugin in my MVC application. The chosen plugin use to work well with my site. However, I have additionally used ajax-chosen to take advantage of ajax capabilities with this framework. But this doesn't seem to be a good deal till now.

First of all, when user is presented with the filtered list of options, and if s/he presses down key (which obviously selects the first option), but after that if user presses Tab key directly then it doesn't select the item. It seems that user must have to either press Enter key or have to use mouse. This is quite annoying.

Apart from that, all the styling of dropdownlist which was looking ok with chosen seems lost in ajax-chosen.

Also, I am not sure what is coffeescript file it provides, and for what purpose. there isn't any information provided on its page over Github

Comment: You should consider posting this as 3 separate question 1) form controls, 2) Styling and 3) Coffeescript.  You are more likely to get better quicker responses and the questions/answer will apply to others.  Right now this is a bit too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have dropped the idea of using Chosen controller, and using Select2 which is quite seamless,easy to implement, and user-friendly